# Sed: Look for IP Address between range?

Tags: sed

How does one look for a range in IP Addresses with `sed`?

For example:

```
sed '/85.159.56/s/$/ ---  API SYSTEMS/'
```

This would locate IP Addresses starting with: 85.159.56 and print next to it: ---  API SYSTEMS

What I have a range to filter and I'm unsure how to apply a between or greater than in `sed`:

```
 sed '/192.200.160.0 - 192.200.191.255/s/$/ ---  APIv2 SYSTEMS/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Number ranges are a poor fit for regular expressions, as they require such expressions as

```
gsed '/192\.200\.1\([6-8][0-9]\|9[01]\)\./s/$/ --- APIv2 SYSTEMS/'
```

to match between 160 and 191, so ideally you would need to write code that could generate the expression, as the odds of human error manually writing or modifying such would be extremely high. A better solution may be something that understands IP addresses and supports CIDR notation, e.g. the Perl [NetAddr::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr::IP) module, and then to parse the IP addresses and check whether they are `->within` some range parsed from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

## Short'ish (non-SED) Answer

Sorry, but this is the best I could do in a one-liner. Obviously, it isn't SED.

```
perl -MNetAddr::IP -i.bak -nle '$re=NetAddr::IP->new("85.159.56.0/24")->re(); if(/$re/){ print $_ . " --- APIv2 SYSTEMS"}else{print}' yourfile.txt
```

### What it does

This will take the subnet "85.159.56.0/24" and turn it into a regular expression, then test each line for that expression, if there's a match it will add " --- APIv2 SYSTEMS" to the end of the line.

- "-Mmodule" loads a module before running the code.
- "-i.bak" means that it will modify the file (yourfile.txt) in-place and make a backup as yourfile.txt.bak
- "-n" causes Perl to loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk
- "-s" allows you to set arguments outside of the program
- and " -- -variable=X" is how we set it.
- "-l" is because I'm lazy, it cleans the input line and appends a carriage return to any output
- finally "-e 'print "I'm a one-liner"' is the bit that holds the code

### Just the REGEX

If you just want the regex (to used in grep or sed/awk etc):

```
perl -MNetAddr::IP -lse 'print NetAddr::IP->new($range)->re()' -- -range=85.159.56.0/24
```

Which outputs the following if you're curious:

```
(?:(?<![0-9])85\.159\.(?:56)\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?![0-9]))
```

### Pre-Requisite

It's worth noting that you may need to install the NetAddr::IP module from cpan (I use cpanm because I don't have enough memory but the syntax is the same:

```
sudo cpanm install NetAddr::IP
```

### Closing comment

SED and AWK are fantastic tools, I genuinely have a couple of books on them and try to use them where necessary, however Perl usually has your back with it's range of modules and the whole one-liner thing. I'm pretty sure Python has these sorts of tools too, but I'm a Perl fan.
Can I also just recommend http://explainshell.com which I use frequently to figure out what someone has asked me to run. It takes the command and the various switches/arguments and just shows you the relevant part of the man pages.